# Is there any way to get the files from some external source (API) and attach them in the new email through Outlook Add-in using OfficeJs

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, email-attachments, outlook-web-addins

Is there any way to get the files from some external source (API) and attach them in the new email through Outlook Add-in using OfficeJs apart from Share point online (Office365) and OneDrive.

Solution approach for implementing attachments functionality from the add-in for external source files and emails

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You may be interested in the [addFileAttachmentAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-preview&preserve-view=true#outlook-office-messagecompose-addfileattachmentasync-member(1)) method which adds a file to a message or appointment as an attachment. The `addFileAttachmentAsync` method downloads the file at the specified URI and attaches it to the item in the compose form.

```
        Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(
            `https://webserver/picture.png`,
            'picture.png',
            { asyncContext: null },
            function (asyncResult) {
                if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                    write(asyncResult.error.message);
                } else {
                    // Get the ID of the attached file.
                    const attachmentID = asyncResult.value;
                    write('ID of added attachment: ' + attachmentID);
                }
            });
```

See [Manage an item's attachments in a compose form in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-and-remove-attachments-to-an-item-in-a-compose-form) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for the answer.

Can I get the files like word, PDF, Excel etc from specified URI by using  addFileAttachmentAsync method.

Comment: It doesn't matter what extension the file has.